# How are mulitple C++ std::string variables concatenated by GCC?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, compiler-construction, concatenation

I'm interested in the internal implementation of `std::string` concatenation in GCC. Specifically, suppose I want to concatenate some relatively large strings, `a` and `b`.  I'm quite wary of string concatenation in general, whereas strings are immutable in a lot of high-level languages.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::string a = "This would be some kind of data.";
  std::string b = "To be concatenated with this, and other things.";

  // Is building c this way equivalent to strcpy'ing a, ' ', b, and '\n' into
  // a sufficiently large chunk of memory, or are intermediate variables used
  // and discarded?
  std::string c = a + ' ' + b + '\n';
  std::cout << c;
}
```

Is building `c` this way equivalent to `strcpy`'ing `a`, `' '`, `b`, and `'\n'` into a sufficiently large chunk of memory, or are intermediate variables used and discarded?

Comment: The content of `a` ends up being copied 3 times, you would need expression templates or at least rvalue references to do better. By the way, reading the source is a good way to know what it does...

Comment: @MarcGlisse When I get a chance I'll trawl through the GCC source code to see if I can find it.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h?revision=213873&view=markup

Answer (score 1):

`std::string c = a + ' ' + b + '\n';` will do:

```
std::string tmp1 = a.operator+('');
std::string tmp2 = tmp1.operator+(b);
std::string c = tmp2.operator+('\n');
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/

> Concatenate strings Returns a newly constructed string object with its
>   value being the concatenation of the characters in lhs followed by
>   those of rhs.

With enabled optimizations, compiler will/might remove these unnecessary copies

Or pre allocate the string manually.

```
std::string c;
c.reserve(a.size()+1+b.size()+1);
c += a;
c += ' ';
c += b;
c += '\n';
```

Now it won't create that temporary objects.
Even without `reserve`. It won't reallocate that often (on large strings).
Because buffers grow `new_size=2*size` (in libstdc++)

See also [std::string and its automatic memory resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557591/stdstring-and-its-automatic-memory-resizing)

Also worth mentioning C++11 can `std::move` memory, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620055/362904

Comment: Holy smokes, really?  That's what I was worried about!  You've got a typo, though; `a` is missing from your logic.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Just for log, I updated the answer and fixed the typo